# Java-Is there a way to get MouseEvents with a modal dialog up or make a non-modal dialog wait until input?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, mouseevent, modal-dialog

I am working on a program that is meant to keep track of footraces.  The program is set up so that a right click(though this may be changed) at any time will indicate a runner has passed the finish line.  This is important so that you can do things and still mark a runner as passing at any point.  To finish the race and compile results, there is a button. To prevent a misclick from prematurely stopping the timer, I have a dialog that confirms while the timer is still running.  This dialog is also right-clickable to mark a runner as passing.  I have a method that gets the input from the dialog as a boolean.

```
public static boolean showDialog(Frame parent, boolean modal,String text,RacePanel r)
    {
        ConfirmBox c=new ConfirmBox(parent,modal,text);//this makes the dialog
        for(Component comp:c.getComponents())//this adds a listener for right-click events, to record passing runners
            r.addListener(comp);
        c.setVisible(true);
        return c.yes;//yes is the boolean that should be returned
    }
```

I originally had the dialog modal, so that the `setVisible` method would wait for the dialog to close.  However, this made the program ignore mouse clicks on the rest of the screen.  When I set it as not modal, this showDialog method returned immediately, which was always false.  I don't actually care if the dialog is modal or not.

Is there a way to get MouseEvents with a modal dialog up or make a non-modal dialog wait until input?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of solutions:

- Use hot keys to react - will be faster. so F11 means stop race, with F12 to confirm it. And F9 to indicate a runner has passed the finish line
  There are JNI packages for this like at http://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/
- Have the user click the button and type a key or world like "end" for a sample see http://code.google.com/p/baby-smash/source/browse/src/quick/KeyBoardListen.java Do not like a dialog box as they take time to render and can increase to the timer.
- If you must use a dialog box then implement your own. in that class take an instance of your main class (or interface that your controller implements) then call a method on the controller when window is acted on (yes or no pressed or window closed - default). In the window close do not close the window but just hide it. this will mean you can show it faster next time. You can also load this class on start up to make it ready in the background
- **If you just want mouse events** can try extending JFrame and then over ride (javadoc of java.awt.Component):
  protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e)

Processes mouse events occurring on this component by dispatching them to any registered MouseListener objects.

This method is not called unless mouse events are enabled for this component. Mouse events are enabled when one of the following occurs:

```
A MouseListener object is registered via addMouseListener.
Mouse events are enabled via enableEvents.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use listeners to listen for changes in the dialog class's state. For instance a WindowListener can listen for the dialog's window closing. If you want to listen for other state changes in the dialog's classes, consider creating "bound" properties or fields by use of a PropertyChangeListener.

Comment: What do you mean by "bound"?  Also, with listeners, how would I implement it so that I can use the `showDialog` code to get a boolean, like it works with the above method and a modal dialog?

Comment: @BillThePlatypus: It all depends on exactly what you're trying to listen for -- the press of a button? The change in value of a field or property? The closing of a dialog? What?